# Jquery how to copy input field value on clipboard automatically after ajax success response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

What I achieved is I can copy link on click event by using Clipboard.js 
but I also want to copy an input field value on the clipboard automatically after an ajax success response.
How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: please add an example and show what you've tried.

Comment: this is basic demo of my work https://jsfiddle.net/16rwx27p/

Comment: what i want is when i got the success response the input field value automatically copied to clip board

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`document.execCommand('copy')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands)

```js
function copyText() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('txt');
  input1.select();
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```html
<input id='txt' required />

<input type="submit" value="copy" onclick="copyText()" />
<br>
<br>
<textarea placeholder="Paste it here"></textarea>
```

For your req:

**(From the fiddle you've mentioned in comment)**

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url,
   async: false,
   data: data
   success: function(response) {
     $("#shortlink").val(response);
     $('#shortlink').select();
     document.execCommand('copy')
   },
   error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {

   }
 });
```

Comment: how can i do it without click event?

Comment: when do you want to call it ?

Comment: When i get the response from ajax request success then after success link should be copied..   `  $.ajax({
                url : $url,
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                    data
                },
                success : function( response ) {  I want to copy the link  which is response}`

Comment: where the link will be binded? input field?

Comment: @rjcomtech when the ajax will get called.

Comment: I have tried that but on success It only select the field value  but the field value is not copied.

Comment: I think document.execCommand('copy') is not executed on ajax success response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129193/discussion-between-sankar-raj-and-rjcomtech).

Comment: @rjcomtech try now... I have made the request synchronous.